# Is there any opensource tool to automate Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, testing, automation

I am looking for opensource option to automate one of my Silverlight application. Application contains Silverlight objects like map, zooming, graphs, tooltips appearing on graphs, expander etc.

Anyone idea about IronRuby, Silverlight automation peer? I mean how does it work and how useful it would be for automation of application containing above silverlight objects?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Code UI for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269472.aspx)?